# Mutiple css classes with a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I set mulitple CSS classes for an HTML element, with at least one normal class and one or more Javascript variables as classes?

Here's how I tried to do it, putting it in like a normal script:

```
<div class="style-a <script type="text/javascript">style-b</script>">
```

Then I saw that someone recommend this:

```
<div onload="this.class=style-a;">
```

But I'm pretty sure that would only work for one class.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this.class` wouldn't work for any classes, as it's `this.className`. In newer browser you can use `this.classList.add('style-a')`.

Comment: Have you tried separating the class names with a space to get multiple class names? Something like `this.class='style-a class2'`?

Comment: @Patrick548 No, I hadn't. I'll try that.

Comment: Neither of the above solutions worked for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setAttribute

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
element.setAttribute('class','class1 class2');
```

See it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/cyonb8v9/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert script elements in html attributes to insert data computed by dynamically evaluated code.

Instead you might apply the following template:

```
<div id="#dyn-styles-1" class="style-a">
    <!-- div contents -->
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<script>
    //
    // Beware:
    //  - Execute _after_ the complete DOM has been built ( use handlers for `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` events)
    //  - Proof of concept only: coding style not recommended for production code
    //
    var js_var_containing_class = "style-b";

    //...

    document.getElementById("dyn-styles-1").className = document.getElementById("dyn-styles-1").className + " " + js_var_containing_class;

</script>
```

You need not rely on IDs but may refer to existing css classes instead:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("style-a");

for (var i=0; i< el.length; i++) {
    el[i].className = el[i].className + " " + js_var_containing_class;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason the class stays "style-a". Not sure why. Thanks though.